# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

В ужасе перед грядущим(,) я задремал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужна запятая, так как нельзя "задремать в ужасе".

Здесь обязательная актуализация и обособление обстоятельства, близкого по значению к деепричастному обороту "ощущая себя в ужасе перед грядущим".

Comment: >> Нужна запятая, так как нельзя "задремать в ужасе".

Забавно. По-моему, так: предложение необходимо перестроить, так как нельзя задремать в ужасе. А вы предлагаете спасти дело, поставив запятую. Но запятая не спасает. Действительно, нельзя "задремать в ужасе". И "ощущая себя в ужасе перед грядущим" (что само по себе сомнительно), тоже задремать нельзя, не верите - попробуйте. ))))

Answer (score 1):

Предложение очень странное. Как это "задремал в ужасе"? Ни запятая, ни ее отсутствие корявую фразу не спасают.

Comment: Люди засыпают от стресса, если до этого долго не спали. Не говорю уже о тех, у кого депрессия — они целыми днями спать могут.

Comment: Да, но "в ужасе" все равно заснуть нельзя. Депрессия так депрессия, долго не спал - так долго не спал. Вы разницу чувствуете? Можно, грубо говоря, ужас нафиг послать и заснуть, но в ужасе заснуть нельзя.

Comment: Я Вас понимаю, но есть контекст. Герой долгое время прибывает в рабстве, всё это время переживает жуткий стресс: не знает, когда решится его судьба. И вот он узнаёт, что решится она сегодня ночью и, уже совсем истощённый эмоционально (но ясное дело — в ужасе), засыпает. Если хотите, это как ночь перед экзаменом, когда у тебя самый крепкий и сладкий сон, но ты всё равно в ужасе перед грядущим! :)

Comment: Да уж... Никогда не был в ужасе в ночь перед экзаменом, ну ладно. )))))

Запятая не нужна, просто нет никаких причин для постановки. Никакого деепричастного оборота, как утверждает София, и близко нет.

Comment: Я же говорю - актуализация обстоятельства, подчеркнутая пауза, ИНТОНАЦИЯ предложения ТАКАЯ ЖЕ, как при обособлении обстоятельственных или деепричастных оборотов. Это не интонация простого предложения, где пауза только обозначает переход тона.

Comment: Однако это не причина ставить запятую. Никогда не видел "при актуализации обстоятельства ставьте запятую". В крайнем случае - авторский знак. Да и то слишком натянуто.

Comment: Актуализация - это и есть обособление, переход от одного сообщения "в ужасе перед грядущим я задремал" к двум сообщениям: (1) я был в ужасе перед грядущим и (2) я задремал. И никакого авторства, иначе будете сегодня "дремать в ужасе", если, конечно, не согласитесь поставить запятую (смайлик).